# Remove item on long Click Listener in list

Tags: android, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

i  want to remove item from list onsetOnItemLongClickListener.i have called agetAssetData method from database class and add it to list and call this delete method in on create method but on clicking item on list its not showing any option for delete as mentioned in my code .

```
    dataModelAssetDataArrayList =
            new ArrayList <>(databaseAssetData.getAssetData());

    dataAdapterAssetData = new DataAdapterAssetData(this, dataModelAssetDataArrayList);

public void DeleteItem(){

    listViewAssetData.setAdapter(dataAdapterAssetData);

    listViewAssetData.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int position, long arg3) {
            removeItemFromList(position);

            return true;
        }


        // method to remove list item
        protected void removeItemFromList(int position) {
            final int deletePosition = position;

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    EditViewAssetDataActivity.this);

            alert.setTitle("Delete");
            alert.setMessage("Do you want delete this item?");
            alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TOD O Auto-generated method stub

                    // main code on after clicking yes
                    list.remove(deletePosition);
                    dataAdapterAssetData.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dataAdapterAssetData.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  list.remove(deletePosition);    
  dataModelAssetDataArrayList.remove(deletePosition); //Must remove before notifyDataSetChanged
  dataAdapterAssetData.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i tried but its not working, firstly on long click on item its not showing any option like -do you want to delete, message,why?

Comment: first i want to show alert message on long click press on items

Comment: removeItemFromList(position);

            return false; try this